# textbox css hover and button display asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I want some css code and javascript to my textbox and a button, For First time my button is hide

1. when my mouse goes to the text box it height should be increased and then i remove my mouse on another place that that increased size should be kept.
2. when my mouse goes to the textbox a button should be visible and then i remove my mouse on another place that button should be visible.

This is CSS file now i am using, but i want to make some changes for this if i want to get upper things.

```
#TextBox1 {
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
height: 30px;
width:510px;
padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc inset;
transition: 500ms all ease;
outline: 0;
}

#TextBox1:hover {
height: 100px;  

}
```

Post button css

```
#Post {
        background: rgb(66, 184, 221); /* this is a light blue */
        border-radius: 20px;

    }
```

how to change this css files as i want? I think I need a javascript file also to hide and visible post button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the textbox and the post button in one div and use the following CSS.

First HTML

```
<div class="textBoxWrapper" >
    <textarea class="textbox_1" id="TextBox1" ></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="post" value="Post me"></input>
</div>
```

Now the CSS

```css
#TextBox1 {
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
height: 30px;
width:510px;
padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc inset;
transition: 500ms all ease;
outline: 0;
}

#TextBox1:hover {
height: 100px;  

} 



#Post {
    background: rgb(66, 184, 221); /* this is a light blue */
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.textBoxWrapper:hover > #Post {
display: block;

}
```

Pure CSS-solution for question number 2.

For number 1 I would use JavaScript

```css
 .TextBox1Large {
     height: 100px;
 }
```

```cs
<asp:textbox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:textbox>

<script>
    document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").addEventListener("mouseover", changeHeightOfTextBox, false);

    function changeHeightOfTextBox() {
        document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").className = "TextBox1Large";
        //Delete the event, since it is needed only once.
        document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").removeEventListener("mouseover", changeHeightOfTextBox, false);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: dude, error comes text box does not exit on c# code file. what should i use for  this commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status",TextBox1.Text);

Comment: textbox1 does not exists

Comment: @Prabath I've updated my code with C# reference. Should work for you now.

Comment: @Prabath of course: You need to put this script inside body (`<asp:content>` with id `bodyContent`) of the HTML page. Create `<script></script>` tag and put the JavaScript content in there.

Comment: I added this script to my webpage, but has some errors. [Please click](https://scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/1450926_1501739493448960_5462432286526171192_n.jpg?oh=8d99436c6da54fe0491b10f098b8c9fd&oe=5539ED52) here to see.

Comment: @Prabath please put the script into the body and remove the attribute `runat="server"`. This way the code gets executed when the textbox is present and not at the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would say instead of using the css hover try adding a class to the textbox1 when you detect the focus event for the the textbox1 using jquery. Then at the same time use jQuery to make the button visible.

Example code below:

```
//CSS
#TextBox1Clicked{
    Height: 100px;
}

//jQuery
$(document).on('focus', '#TextBox1', function(){
    //Show the button
    $('#yourButtonId').show();

    //Add the css class to the text box to make it taller
    $('#TextBox1').addClass('TextBox1Clicked');
});
```

Resources:
jQuery '.On':
http://api.jquery.com/on/

jQuery 'addClass':
http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: That's example code with some references to learn. Use the example code and modify it then learn from the resources ;)
good luck.

Comment: what is textbox1clicked? my textbox id is textbox1

Comment: That would be the css Class that has attributes to make the textbox  to make the height bigger.